# PHPSESSID keeps changing on every refresh

Tags: php, session, cookies

Yesterday I ran into a issue. I was doing just hundreds of changes in php.ini and httpd.conf so I couldn't remember which thing is causing this issue.

The exact issue is when I refresh the page it generates a new PHPSESSID. I tried for other browser but I was sure that this is not a broswer issue.

```
Set-cookie: PHPSESSID=2pu27c6fi5cnpropceg5hll473; path=/; secure ---> test.php
Set-cookie: PHPSESSID=8kdqjurmp7tlvdgh7pvqmqjsta; path=/; secure ---> test2.php
```

I am using Apache2.4 and PHP7.4.1
my php.ini setting below

```
session.save_handler = files
session.use_cookies = 1
session.use_only_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain =
session.cookie_httponly =
session.serialize_handler = php
session.gc_probability = 1
session.gc_divisor = 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.bug_compat_42 = On
session.bug_compat_warn = On
session.referer_check =
session.cache_limiter = nocache
session.use_trans_sid = 0
session.hash_function = 0
session.hash_bits_per_character = 5
```

I searched google but didn't found solution. All i got was use `session_start();` also I haven't changes my phpversion so I don't think i should change my .dlls. but I know how to start a session. I need a solution, if anyone ran into this issue and was resolved please tell me.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using suhosin by any chance? If you happen to be, then paste this into your .htaccess:  php_flag suhosin.cookie.encrypt off    --> This fixed my similar problem once.

Comment: well, I am not using suhosin. you think anything else can populate the issue.

Comment: Nah, the obvious causes all seem good in your php.ini. The only other potential problem I could find is that the directory where your sessions are saved is not writable: supposedly you can check that with:  "is_writable(session_save_path())"  --> without the quotes, but I'm not an expert in the nitty gritty, sorry.

Comment: How are you using session in `test.php` and `test2.php`?

Comment: for test.php
`session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = "john doe";`

for test2.php
`session_start();
echo $_SESSION['name'];`

Comment: Try using  `if (session_id()) { session_start(); }` snippet.

Comment: I tried this but after that i see that `Set-Cookie()` disappeared from header.
<br>
it even said `Undefined variable: _SESSION` on `echo $_SESSION`

Comment: Pardon me. Try using `if (! session_id()) { session_start(); }` snippet. I missed negation operator.

Comment: PHPSESSID again changes on test2.php

Comment: Did you use that on both pages?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207649/discussion-between-arpit-patidar-and-unclexo).